# Where is the swagger json schema located?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

The [help for swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml) mentions that the ui for Swagger is driven by the generated json schema.

Where is this json file located?
I cannot find it in the folder for my asp.net project

When I actually run the application and navigate to http://localhost:51659/swagger/v1/swagger.json

then I see the json

Where is it on disk?  Or is it only in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no file generated, it is only on memory.

You might want to read a bit the code:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerGenerator.cs

If you need a file you could create an IDocumentFilter to generate one.
 I have an example here generating a Yaml file:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L378